# MacOS Spotlight does not search djvu files

Tags: spotlight

each time I search for a djvu document file, the spotlight does not index it. I cannot see the files but are there in finder. How can I solve this problem? Maybe it depends on the filter I made on the spotlight search. Can someone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Solved by myself. I did activate the search for "other" files in the spotlight preferences. Thank you anyway.